# How to create a global function which will access DB in express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I use express.js, mongodb, ejs. In the navbar, there's an email icon and will display the count of new emails.

```
<%=newEmailCount%>
```

Then I need to add this newEmailCount to every route.

```
Emails.count({userId: userId, new: true})
```

my question is in express.js, how can I add a global function that can be executed by every route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the count for every `GET` requests then you can use following approach

```
router.get('*', function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.newEmailCount = Emails.count({userId: userId, new: true})
  next();
})
```

You need to make sure this is always executed by placing it above all the other routes.

You can then pass `res.locals.newEmailCount` to your render function which renders HTML file for matched route.

This will work also for application instance level routes handling if that's what you're using.